# Google Chrome with GNOME

Tags: 12.04, google-chrome, window, gnome-shell-extension

I've used Windows for a long time, and I'm used to that Maximize, Minimize and Close buttons are on the upper right corner of a window. I fixed that in GNOME. But, it doesn't affect Google Chrome.

Is there any way to fix that?

I use GNOME 3.4.2.1 in Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: How did you try to fix it?

Comment: Have you selected "use GTK window borders" in Chrome preferences?

Answer (score 1):

Google chrome does really follow the old fix. You should use this command to put them in right.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout ':minimize,maximize,close'
```

This worked for me. You can also do the same using dconf-editor.